# 2gb FTP resume limit on centos

Tags: centos, ftp

I am relatively new to using linux but is there any way to allow my centos install to resume files larger then 2gb in size. If so how can this be done? I am running CentOS release 5.3 (Final) Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What FTP server are you using?

Comment: pure-ftpd i think... For some reason my ftp service isn't even running now... I usually manage my ftp users via lxadmin - but now no one can connect to the ftp - I have no idea what has happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to solve the Resume limit issues - however the problems with starting pure-ftpd were resolved in a different question asked: [my pure-ftpd server on centos is not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/68479/my-pure-ftpd-server-on-centos-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I am curious.  If you enable the SSHD daemon on port 22 and SFTP (via the SSHD ftp module) using a SFTP client, what limit do you encounter?