# my pure-ftpd server on centos is not working

Tags: centos, ftp

I am relatively new to linux and am running centos 5.3 on my VPS. I manage my ftp users via lxadmin - The ftp server that my vps is running is pure-ftpd I believe however recently it has stopped working. Could someone tell me how to restart this service. I have tried running

```
 /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd restart
```

But this seems to have no effect. I may be wrong. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
/etc/init.d/pure-ftpd restart
```

Or:

```
service pure-ftpd restart
```

Comment: When I run this command I get FAILED - Is there a way to show why it's failing?

Comment: check error messages with: tail -f /var/log/messages

Comment: I think it's to do with when I ran yum update it updated 
pure-ftpd - 1.0.20-32.i386 to  pure-ftpd-1.0.21-1.el5.rf.i386 which might have messed with the config file or something.

Comment: I see, I think is a weird issue with pure-ftpd running on a CentOS VPS. Take a look at this link http://achmadz.blogspot.com/2009/08/getting-pure-ftpd-works-on-centos-53.html for more information about it.

Comment: Thanks you so much! spent ages on this problem and was debating switching from pure-ftpd because of it! cheers for the advice :)